# Is there any way to query a MySQL stored procedure for its returned column names and their data types?

Tags: mysql, .net, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

Is there any way to automatically find out the returned column names of a stored procedure and their data types?

Assuming my stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `user_countries`()
BEGIN
select m.ID, m.Name, c.Country
from Member AS m, Country AS c
where m.CountryId = c.ID;
END$$
```

This returns me a table which looks like this:

```
ID    |  Name  |  Country
-------------------------
1       John      USA
2       Mary      Australia
```

I need to be able to query my stored procedure so that I can see something like the following

```
ColName   |    Data Type    
------------------------
ID        |    INT
Name      |    Varchar(50)
Country   |    Varchar(50)
```

I have not heard of anything that can be done for a stored procedure similar to the table equivalent of

> describe Member;

Any suggestions?

PS. This is just a trivial example, I have hundreds of tables and hundreds of stored procedures of varying complexity which I need to analyze.

---

**ANSWER**
Thanks to @BishnuPaudel from the comments below.

I am connecting to the db via c# .net so the approach was to query the data which was returned from the stored procedure rather than accessing it via mysql commands.

Using the example from the msdn library

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns(v=vs.110).aspx

I have added the column.DataType print statement to see the Datatypes of the column.

```
    private void PrintValues(DataTable table) {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(column.DataType);
                Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think so. What if the procedure contains an `IF`, and executes a different `SELECT` depending on it, and they return different columns?

Comment: What client you are using (PHP, .NET...) ? The best bet would be to check the type of returned collection from client side code.

Comment: Good point @Barmar , still, I am thinking about whether it would be possible to have some kind of wrapper stored procedure which would return what I am after even if the stored proc has an IF with potentially different result sets.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel Im using .net. Any idea how to do this without using something like the entity framework. At the moment I have it in a weakly typed object which is why I was looking if there was a way at the db level to assist with this.

Comment: I assumed you needed to do this without actually calling the function. If you call the function, most SQL APIs provide a way to get this information about the result that was returned.

Comment: @Barmar This sounds like a similar suggestion to BishnuPaudel. Are you aware of where to look for these API methods? I would assume mysql .netConnector documentation would be a good place to start. Or should I look from a .net perspective at some data handling objects (unlikely)

Comment: Since I know nothing about .net, I can't help you there.

Comment: @Brad In .NET, you can read the results of the stored procedure into a DataTable which requires execution of stored procedure in MySQL and querying the Columns property of DataTable object.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel You got it!         private void PrintValues(DataTable table) {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(column.DataType);
                    Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
                }
            }
        }    

The column.DataType attribute holds the datatype information from the database query. I need to just automate calling all stored procs and print them all out with column name and datatype. :)
Thanks All!